# How to push code into two different folders?

Tags: git, github

We are having a project on git, that contains web content and phone content. but when someone from website developers push their files to git all files from phone content that were previously are gone and update with webcontent.. what i want to do is create two folders in repo named web and phone , and respective people push to respective folder.. so how to do this.. help with detailed instructions ... Thanks in advance
I followed this link but didn't got d ans
https://help.github.com/

Comment: Why not create two repositories? Also, files are not simploy "gone" – you have to remove them manually or do a force-push

Comment: we are in a organization event.. so they have provided us repo & we have to push to it only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With git, you cannot "push to a folder". You commit to a repo and push to a remote repo.

So if you want two different directories in your repo, you just create them (linux: `mkdir <dir>`), place the files there, add that files `git add web/<file> phone/<file>`, commit them `git commit -m "<msg>"` and push them `git push origin master`.

So the files in are in different directories and will not be overwritten by files in another directory.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this with git.

there are two solutions:

### simple and good

If a dev only works on the`web` folder then
they should only `commit` files in this folder
and NEVER files that they are not working on (e.g. in the `phone` folder).
Then, when they *push* their changes, they will not remove anything in the *other* folder.

### complicated and complex

you could also setup two different git repositories, "foo-web" and "foo-phone", and make your devs only work on the repository they want.

in your "full" application, you then use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/de/Git-Tools-Submodule) to integrate the two repositories.

Answer (score -1):

Here is very simple ans that I got from having ideas from above ans mentioned. .. just make sure you are in that directory that u want to make changes.. copy files or make changes to folders/ files in that directory. . Now get status.. by command git status.. u will get changes .. make a commit by entering ...git commit -m "your message" ...... and u are ready to push to that specific  directory...enter push command....git push origin master..... boom!!!!!!!!

Comment: apart from the dismal formatting of your anwer, how is this different from *any* documentation about using git?

Comment: @umläute  I got answer by having this method